# Upload file to S3 direct from the browser using POST

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Similar to this question:
[Enabling POST/PUT/DELETE on AWS CloudFront?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909827/enabling-post-put-delete-on-aws-cloudfront)

I have setup a Cloudfront Distribution with an Origin Access Identity that has access to the S3 origin.

S3 has a CORS configuration that allows PUT, POST, GET, etc. from any Origin. Cloudfront is forwarding the Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers & Access-Control-Request-Method headers to the S3 origin.

Using the Dropzone-js library I have configured a POST upload request to the Cloudfront endpoint.

> Response: 405 Method Not Allowed

And the Response headers:

- access-control-allow-methods  HEAD, GET, PUT, POST
- access-control-allow-origin   *
- allow     HEAD, DELETE, GET, PUT
- server AmazonS3
- x-cache   Error from cloudfront

If I switch the request method to 'PUT' the upload response is successful.

200 OK

- x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
- access-control-allow-methods  HEAD, GET, PUT, POST

The mysterious '**allow**' header is now missing.

The file that ends up in S3 following the PUT request is not readable. I get an Access Denied error when trying to download it.

```
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

I'm not sure if S3 implicitly refuses POST requests. That would be fine, so long as PUT requests worked.

The CORS configuration:

```
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

The Bucket Policy:

```
{
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXX"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket.net/*"
}
```

s3:* is to try and get it working for a start.

Why is POST not allowed to the S3 Origin?
Why is the uploaded file corrupt/not readable?

I've also tried pre-signed URLs similar to method below, but face similar problems. POST is rejected, and PUT is AccessDenied. I tried this on multiple buckets. The only way it would work is with Public WRITE enabled.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/deep-dive-into-cors-configs-on-aws-s3-how-to/

Edit:
This issue is very similar, but appears to not be resolved.
[dropzone.js direct upload to S3 with content-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47338927/dropzone-js-direct-upload-to-s3-with-content-type)

Comment: The uploaded file isn't corrupted. Your IAM user doesn't have the right to call the Head object, ie. Metadata. Is it possible for you to try this with a s3 all access account just to confirm that it is an access issue?

Comment: I believe the keys I'm using to inspect, as well as the console access account have full access rights. I created the bucket, there is nothing I can't do in S3. Except when I upload a file by this method. Also, turning Public Read on does not give me access to the uploaded files

Answer (score 0):

> Why is POST not allowed to the S3 Origin?

`POST` requests for S3 origin in CloudFront with OAI are simply **not supported**.

From [Using an OAI in Amazon S3 Regions that Support Only Signature Version 4 Authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#private-content-origin-access-identity-signature-version-4):

> **POST requests are not supported**.

Comment: That explains that then. The linked page also talks about a ' x-amz-content-sha256' header required for PUT requests via Cloudfront to S3. This is the first time I've seen requirement, but it may explain the other part of this problem.

Comment: @comfytoday I'm not sure about the corrupted data when you PUT objects. It could be that some headers are missing as you noticed.